# How to unmount LVM automatically at shutdown (Debian/Ubuntu)?

Tags: lvm, init.d

I've created an LVM2 script in /etc/init.d/lvm2 and registered it with update-rc for startup, now the manuals I am reading states "immediately *after* all filesystems were unmounted:" that this should be ran:

```
vgchange -a n
```

Where would I place this script, so that it is called to unmount all mounted LVM partitions?

Will I need to implement "start" and "stop" parameters somehow in to my lvm2 script and use update-rc to tell them to use those? I am not sure.

Comment: Isn't it done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I need to implement "start" and "stop" parameters somehow in to my lvm2 script

Yes, if you use update-rc or create link in /etc/rc?.d.

> and use update-rc to tell them to use those?

Yes, if you need it to run at startup or shutdown of the system.